# Proving there is always a unique solution to $A^TAx = A^Tb$ and that $b - Ax$ is orthogonal to $R(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n \times k$ matrix of rank $k$ and $b \in R^n$, how can I prove there is always a unique solution to $A^TAx = A^Tb$ and that $b - Ax$ is orthogonal to $R(A)$?

I know the dimension of $A^T = k$ since $rank(A) = k$, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse

Answer (score 1):

First show that $\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)=k$ and note that $A^TA\in\Bbb R^{k\times k}$ and $A^Tb \in \Bbb R^k$. Uniqueness and existence of the solution should follow from these facts.

For the orthogonality, note that for every $y\in R(A)$ there is $u$ such that $Au=y$, in particular if $A^TAx = A^Tb$, then  $$\langle b-Ax,y\rangle = \langle b-Ax,Au\rangle= \langle A^T(b-Ax),u\rangle=\ldots$$